# Create invoice programmatically and capture online not working while running from cron

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, cron, programmatically

I'm currently facing a weird result with my script when running it by cron.
This script is creating the invoice and capture the amount online.

```
if($order->canInvoice()) {

  $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
  $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
  $invoice->register()->pay(); 

  Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
      ->addObject($invoice)
      ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
      ->save();

  $invoice->sendEmail();

}
```

It works fine when I call the cron by Magento backend AEOScheduler, then "RunNow".

The problem is when the cron is executed automatically by crontab.
The invoice is created successfully but the event "sales_order_invoice_pay" seems not fired. This is the event catched by my payment processor extension for capturing correctly the amount ONLINE.

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<?php

if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}

$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
    ->prepareInvoice();

if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
    Mage::throwException(
        Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.')
    );
}

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(
    Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE
);

$invoice->addComment('Invoice genrated automatically');
$invoice->register();

$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($order);

$transactionSave->save();

try {
    $invoice->sendEmail(true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::logException($e);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
        ->addError($this->__('Unable to send the invoice email.'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the capture method of the invoice instead the pay method in order to get the amount captured. The pay method just sets the invoice to paid but capture gets in touch with you PSP and captures the desired amount.

Comment: If you look at the register method in invoice model, you'll see that capture method is called if setRequestedCaptureCase is setted as ONLINE (that's my case). When I run my cron through backend AOEScheduler, the amount is captured online successfully. But not with "real" cron. Do you have an idea why?